# Weird. My Flair now reports the rep from ALL of my SE sites

Tags: bug, reputation, flair

I just noticed that my flair no longer shows just the pictures and summed reputation from sites that I have 200+ rep. Instead, it's summing the reputation from *all* of my registered sites (and showing as many site pictures as it can fit), regardless of my total reputation at those sites.

However, the flair page still says:

> please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear

My flair was not doing this as of earlier this week.

Is this a bug or did the policy/mechanics of how flair works change?

Comment: @Mithrandir oh hmmm.. Seems we have the same "problem." I saw your question title and just assumed it was about someone --for some reason -- not knowing that rep is rounded up on flair :p.

Comment: Heh. A CM thought that too, and he posted an answer. I told him nope, not what I'm looking for, and he deleted it :P

Comment: @Mithrandir A dev, not a CM. ;) But yeah, something does seem to be off here. We'll dig further.

Comment: I wonder how widespread this is... Not that I mind ... It practically doubled the combined rep reported on my flair ;p

Comment: @AdamLear the combined flair is showing hidden accounts icons. It's a minor privacy issue, but definitely a bug that needs to be fixed soon.

Comment: @Zanon Has it been reported before? If not, would you mind writing it up as a separate post so we can track it? Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear, thank you. I've posted it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291286/combined-flair-is-showing-hidden-accounts).