# Combined flair is showing hidden accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, combined-flair, hidden-communities

The combined flair started to display in this week site icons from hidden accounts. For example, this is my current flair:

[image: combined flair]

The freehand red circle shows a hidden community that you can't see in my [Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1594304/zanon?tab=accounts).

This issue looks to me as a **privacy issue**. Being associated with a SciFi community or Arqade is not a bad thing for my serious work-only profile, but it could be indeed an issue for people trying to hide association with a *religious* community due to the dark times that we are living on.

<sup>I know that this question is similar to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291221/should-my-flair-include-sites-with-less-than-200-reputation), but I'm posting this as [a suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291243/weird-my-flair-now-reports-the-rep-from-all-of-my-se-sites#comment945697_291243) of Adam Lear</sup>

Comment: You mean that hidden communities did not show up in the network flair? I was under the impression that in such case there would be a [tag:status-completed] tag but there is none. (and bug report asking to fix something vs. feature request asking to add the same thing are the same as long as there is no response from the team.)

Comment: OK, not sure what's going on, so I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: Not marking as [status-completed] at your request because there was [another bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291221/155160) that involved showing reputation/icons from all sites rather than just the ones with 200+ reputation. You have < 200 rep on SciFi, so fixing that also removed the icon from your flair. As far as I recall from the code (and I'm reasonably certain, since I fixed the rep threshold issue), the hidden sites are still not considered at all. I'll make a note to take a look at that next week.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is fixed now.

[image: combined flair]

Thanks to Adam Lear for digging into this bug.

Comment: I just pushed the change to exclude hidden communities from the network flair. Live in production now, though there may be some caching involved before existing flairs can regenerate.