# Maximum number of sites shown on combined profile flair?

Tags: support, flair, combined-flair

I use the Stack Exchange Combined flair on my personal website.

[image: profile for Nimesh Neema on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

I understand the criterion of inclusion for a SE network in this list, and also that the participating sites are shown listed in the decreasing order of total reputation.

I noticed that recently my Combined flair started displaying 6 instead of 5 sites. I am curious to know if there is a maximum number of sites that can be displayed in the Combined flair?

Also, does setting a site as hidden removes it from the Combined flair?

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291286/323179