# Stack Exchange says flair is not available because I have less than 200 rep, but I do have more than 200

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, combined-flair, hidden-communities

This is what I see when viewing my global flair:

[image: flair showing a message you don't have 200 rep]

It says:

> You do not have any linked accounts with 200+ rep ☹

But, I do have more 200+ reputation on one of the sites.

I see the above on https://stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=flair

I have 200+ reputation from a long time ago.

Comment: I'm certain that will solve this issue, but perhaps you have to wait 24-36 hours because of caching.

Comment: @Glorfindel there must be a warning that says that hidden profiles will not appear in the flair

Comment: You want to hide a profile, but at the same time you want it to be visible on the flair. Why? The link directs users to their own personal profile page, you could post a screenshot instead.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, I did not say that. I did not know that my profile was hidden. I might have hidden it some day. I don't remember. That is why I asked this question. Sorry if I was too fast in asking it. I believe I should've checked better. I am very sorry. **Also, I hid it from a specific site thinking that it will only hide the profile from that "*Communities*" thing in that site's profile**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have [hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253599/295232) your account with 200+ reputation. It wouldn't really be hidden if it appeared on your flair, would it? That [used to be the case a while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291286/295232) but they have fixed that bug.